# automated activation and configuration of gnome-shell extension

Tags: gnome-shell

I'd like to automatically install and configure a gnome-shell extension, specifically the [Simpler Off Menu](https://extensions.gnome.org/extension/3070/simpler-off-menu/). What I achieved so far is to download the extension, then expand the archive with correct privileges and the correct name into `/usr/share/gnome-shell/extensions/`. The effect is that when I install and run gnome-tweaks I can see the extension but it is still deactivated and after activation still needs to be configured.

All documentation I find is about GUI handling. How can I activate and configure an extension (or specifically this one) so that it is active similar as the Ubuntu default ones (Desktop Icons, Ubuntu AppIndicators, Ubuntu Dock)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The activation of a gnome-shell extension can be triggered with '`dconf`' from the command line.

See the [Gnome documentation](https://help.gnome.org/admin/system-admin-guide/stable/extensions-enable.html.en) for detailed installation and activation instructions.

See the [Ask Ubuntu Forum](https://askubuntu.com/questions/490939/configure-gnome-shell-extensions-from-command-line) for detailed configuration instructions.

Comment: Yes, that answer perfectly matches what I wanted to know. Thank you.

Comment: "[Gnome documentation](https://help.gnome.org/admin/system-admin-guide/stable/extensions-enable.html.en)" does not include installation instructions